# Error passing a value between 2 subroutine

Tags: excel, vba, subroutine

I'm trying to pass a **String** between 2 sub in VBA, but everytime I got a compilation Error

This is my code

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()
    Dim value As String
    value = ComboBox1.value
    ComboBox1_Change value
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change(ByVal value As String)
    Dim value2 As String
    value2 = value
End Sub
```

I am getting the below error

> The routine declaration does not match the description of the event or routine of the same name

I've tried to remove **ByVal** but still nothing... Some tips?

Comment: @SiddharthRout I've edited the question, sorry for the bad syntax

Comment: @BigBen drop the parentheses means to delete them?

Comment: You are still using `valore`... It has to be `value` Also use a different variable name

Comment: @SiddharthRout still getting error...

Comment: you are getting the error because `ComboBox1_Change` doesn't support passing of arguments `ComboBox1_Change(ByVal value As String)` It should be `ComboBox1_Change()`

Comment: @SiddharthRout Ah wow, so how I could pass the value? Should I declare a global variable?

Comment: First, I would like to understand why are you passing a value to `Change` from `DropButtonClick`?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Because I would like to get the value of the dropButton before it get changed. So when User Click on it so `DropButtonClick`, I get the value of the dropButton then when user change it `_Change` I get the new value

Comment: Posted an answer. you may have to refresh the page to see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The routine declaration does not match the description of the event or routine of the same name

You are getting the error because `ComboBox1_Change` doesn't support passing of arguments. `ComboBox1_Change(ByVal value As String)` should be `ComboBox1_Change()`

> @SiddharthRout Because I would like to get the value of the dropButton before it get changed. So when User Click on it, I get the value of the dropButton then when user change it I get the new value – ChangeWorld 10 mins ago

You do not need to add a Global variable. Declare a variable with a scope for within userform. Something like this

```
Option Explicit

Dim oldValue As String
Dim newValue As String

Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()
    oldValue = ComboBox1.value
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    newValue = ComboBox1.value

    MsgBox oldValue
    MsgBox ComboBox1.value
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice explanation! So `oldValue` and `newValue` are not a global variables? But they can be used for many subroutines?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/declaring-variables

Comment: really appreciate the explanation. I would like to ask you one thing. It's a good way of coding to clear the variables when I finish with all the code? So my final code would be `oldValue = ''` and `newValue = ''`?

Comment: I did not understand your above query